# How to remove Lucee / Tomcat / Mura?

Tags: tomcat, lucee, mura

We're experimenting with Lucee / Tomcat / Mura and would like to remove the installed files. Which folders should we be looking in to make sure we have taken out everything? Any tips for wiping out the install completely?

Answer (score 0):

Mura CMS only has files in the folder you've installed it in.

So if you installed it in the root of your web server, you can install all folders in there except for the WEB-INF folder (witch is Lucee related).

If you've installed Mura in a subfolder of the root of your web server, you can remove that folder completely.

But always take a backup before you do, just to be sure you can roll back.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've deleted the folders where it was installed, but when we went to install it again, it said "previous installation detected..."

Comment: I don't see any tables created in the database (unless the Mura install script put them somewhere I can't see...). I'm just using Mysql Workbench, bu tI don't see anything listed there.

Comment: The tables are created using the datasource/database details you provide during the installation wizard. This wizard is loaded the first time you open de website after the installation of the files.

Comment: The wizard never fully loaded after the installation -- it kept saying "unable to load page"...which is why i'm trying to uninstall and try it again.

Comment: If you didn't complete the wizard, the database hasn't been initialised. So don't worry about that.

Comment: That's what i figured. But what confuses me is how, even after I delete the installation folders and try re-installing, it says "Previous instance detected".